# Dynamic (re)creation of iframe content does not reset JS objects in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I'm currently working on a webpage that uses dynamically created iframe content. In that iframe I need to run my own JavaScript code.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="resultsframe" name="resultsframe"></iframe>
<a id="redrawer" href="#">Rerun iframe code</a>
```

JavaScript: (just the basic stuff)

```
var iframe=window.frames['resultsframe'];

var counter = 0;
function redrawFrame() {
    var doc=iframe.document;
    counter++;
    doc.open();
    doc.writeln("<html><body>");
    doc.writeln("Counter: " + counter);
    doc.writeln("<" + "script>");
    doc.writeln("  if (typeof myObj === 'undefined') { var myObj = {}; }");
    doc.writeln("  if (!myObj.initialized) {");
    doc.writeln("    alert('initialize');");          // want this all the time
    doc.writeln("    myObj.initialized = true;");
    doc.writeln("  } else {");
    doc.writeln("    alert('already initialized');"); // ... never this
    doc.writeln("  }");
    doc.writeln("</" + "script>");
    doc.writeln("</body></html>");    
    doc.close(); 
}

redrawFrame();
document.getElementById('redrawer').addEventListener('click', redrawFrame);
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlaM/3n8d5zwz/3/

What I want is that each time the iframe is redrawn the HTML code is added in the frame (restarting with a new page if you want) and execute the javascript code, entering the "not yet initialized" branch and execute the "initialize" alert.

It works in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but Chrome seems to keep myObj even when redrawing, so when the user clicks on "rerun iframe code" the browser will enter the "already initialized" branch.

Any hints how I can make sure that Chrome will also start from a blank frame on each redraw?

---

Just to state the obvious, because I know that these questions will appear:

- The example above is just the condensed version of the problem and does not show the whole game. Of course I could just clean the myObj in my example code - but that's not an option in the real case.
- No: going with iframes was not my decision.
- No: I can't change that.
- Just plain JavaScript - no jQuery.

Comment: myObj  is defined in the window object of iframe which is created only once when iframe is intialized by the browser. on redraw consider deleting old iframe and create new one.

Comment: @Vikash: I was afraid that that might be the only viable answer. That would mean that I need to intrude other people's code responsibility *sigh*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now my working solution is - as [suggested by @Vikash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256850/dynamic-recreation-of-iframe-content-does-not-reset-js-objects-in-chrome#comment46716941_29256850) - to replace the iframe with a newly created one. Doing so was easier than expected - even with the need to duplicate all attributes:

```
function redrawFrame() {
    var frameElement = document.getElementById('resultsframe');
    frameElement.outerHTML = frameElement.outerHTML;

    var doc=iframe.document;
    counter++;
    // ... see above ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using an anonymous function to wrap the code ?

```js
var iframe = window.frames['resultsframe'];

var counter = 0;

function redrawFrame() {
  var doc = iframe.document;

  counter++;

  doc.open();
  doc.writeln("<html rel='" + Math.random() + "'>");
  doc.writeln(" <head>");
  doc.writeln("  <meta http-equiv=content-type content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\" />");
  doc.writeln(" </head>");
  doc.writeln(" <body bgColor=\"#cccccc\">");
  doc.writeln("Counter: " + counter);
  doc.writeln("<" + "script>");
  doc.writeln("(function() {");
  doc.writeln("  if (typeof myObj === 'undefined') { var myObj = {}; }");
  doc.writeln("  alert('in iframe code');");
  doc.writeln("  if (!myObj.initialized) {");
  doc.writeln("    alert('initialize');");
  doc.writeln("    myObj.initialized = true;");
  doc.writeln("  } else {");
  doc.writeln("    alert('already initialized');");
  doc.writeln("  }");
  doc.writeln("})()");
  doc.writeln("</" + "script>");
  doc.writeln("   </body>");
  doc.writeln("</html>");
  doc.close();
  doc = null;
}

redrawFrame();

document.getElementById('redrawer').addEventListener('click', redrawFrame);
```

Tested on Safari which seems to behave like Chrome

Comment: A solution in some cases, but I'm just adding a tiny piece of code to a whole framework of existing stuff - so this is not an option for me. myObj is required to be "global".